# Return data as json from odoo 9

Tags: web-services, odoo, odoo-9, json-rpc, odoo-10

I want get data in JSON format from odoo controllery.py

Example:

```py
import openerp.http as http
from openerp.http import request

class MyController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/test_html', type="http", auth="public")
    def some_html(self):
        return "<h1>Test</h1>"

    #Work fine when open http://localhost:8069/test.html

    @http.route('/test_json', type="json", website=True, auth="public")
    def some_json(self):
        return [{"name": "Odoo", 'website': 'www.123.com'}]
```

How get data in json format, I want data from json read in other app with ajax.

Is it possible view json after open url http://localhost:8069/test_json ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part is to define the contentType of your request properly.

```
import json

@http.route('/test_json', type="json", auth="public")
def some_json(self):
    return json.dumps({"name": "Odoo", 'website': 'www.123.com'})
```

In your client using javascript you can request the json like this.

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/test_json", 
        async: false, 
        data: JSON.stringify({}), 
        contentType: "application/json", 
        complete: function (data) { 
            console.log(data);  
        } 
});
```

Or using requests in python

```
import requests,json

res = requests.post("http://localhost:8069/test_json",data=json.dumps({}),headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})
```

To access the response body

```
body = res.text
```

As to whether you can simply open a browser and view the json. No, not by default.

Here is what I get

```
Bad Request

<function some_json at 0x7f48386ceb90>, /test_json: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'json' but called with a request of type 'http'
```

You could probably do something pretty fancy with a controller if you really wanted to be able to view it in a browser as well as make json requests. I would post a second question though.

Comment: @Philip Stack Tnx for example, Now any simple example how replace  return json.dumps({"name": "Odoo", 'website': 'www.123.com'})  with record from my databse table (res.users).

Comment: To access records you use `http.request.env.user' which would be the current user. To specify a different user `http.request.env['res.users'].sudo().browse([user_id])` from there you can build it into your response variable.

Comment: Hello Phillip, Here is my example https://postimg.org/image/sa4q1miur/  after call get resonse 200, where is problem?

Comment: How view data from controller?

Comment: I will update my answer. It really depends if you are requesting the data from the browser (javascript), or a different server side language.

Comment: I think your question has been addressed, if you could upvote my answer and mark it as correct I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller endpoint looks ok and should function correctly, so I guess your main question is how to test it.

Once you declare that the endpoint type is `json`, Odoo will check that the request content type header is in fact JSON, so in order to test it your requests  will need to have `Content-Type: application/json` header set. This is a bit difficult using a regular browser, unless you edit the request headers before seinding or call your JSON endpoint from JavaScript via Ajax.

Alternatively, you can test your API from command line using a tool like `curl`:

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:8069/test_json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "{}"
```

`--data "{}"` here indicates an empty JSON structure which will be passed to your endpoint as request parameters.

*Please note that you might also have to pass an additional header containing your `session_id` cookie if you are using more than one Odoo database*.

Comment: Wow, we really answered practically exactly the same.

Comment: @Naglis Jonaitas Tnx for help, is it anything online available json from odoo  something like https://odoo.com/simple_json ?